# Android with php: Saving utf-8 string to MySQL

Tags: php, android, utf-8, json

I know I am asking a question that has been asked many times before, but I feel I need clarification on my problem.

I have an Android app that sends a JSON encoded string to a PHP script. The following code then saves the data as a complete JSON string. (There are also other functions to properly save the data to multiple fields, not just as one JSON string)

```
$json_complete = $_POST['questionnaire'];
$q = json_decode($json_complete, true);

//save complete json string to database
$query_upload = "INSERT INTO questions_json (q_id, json) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($q[qID])."', '$json_complete') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE json = VALUES(json)";
$result = mysql_query($query_upload) or errorReport("Error in query: $query_upload. ".mysql_error());
if (!$result)
    errorReport($result);
```

The problem is that some of the text included in the JSON string is taken from strings.xml in Android that is encoded in utf-8. As an example in the strings.xml file `<item>Can\'t get there</item>` is saved as "Canu0027t get there" in MySQL. Also "Wholesale & Retail" is saved as "Wholesale u0026 Retail".

I also had `json_decode()` in php fail on me because of non utf-8 encoded characters in the JSON string. Got the following error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.

How can I handle all these scenarios? Any help please.

Comment: Why json_decode() fails in php ??? Are you getting a wrong string or you have an error message?

Comment: And even if you save Canu0027t get there, when you will display this for example with var a = "Canu0027t get there"; and alert(a); you will see: Canu't get there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to `mysql_real_escape_string()` your `$json_complete` in your query, otherwise you'd loose the original `/uXXXX` encodings.

```
$json_complete = $_POST['questionnaire'];
$q = json_decode($json_complete, true);

//save complete json string to database
$query_upload = "INSERT INTO questions_json (q_id, json) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($q[qID])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($json_complete)."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE json = VALUES(json)";
$result = mysql_query($query_upload) or errorReport("Error in query: $query_upload. ".mysql_error());
if (!$result)
    errorReport($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the encoding for the post?

```
    List<NameValuePair> params = ...;
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(hostname);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I tried that but it made no difference. Still get "it's" saved as "itu0027s"

Answer (score 0):

In general, all strings nowadays should be UTF-8 because it allows for easy internationalization. You should set up your MySQL db such that string fields are stored as UTF-8 (`utf8_general_ci`) and you won't have problems with the conversion.

If you insist on another encoding in your db you may want to check out `mb_check_encoding($string,'UTF-8')`and `mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')`.

Comment: Change my MySQL to utf8_general_ci, but made no difference. Also tried mb_check_encoding and mb_convert_encoding, but also made no difference. Still get "it's" saved as "itu0027s"

Comment: that's weird. so the decoded json contains additional characters whcih are there because php can't decode utf-8 json correctly? or maybe you need to change the way those strings are read from the xml and embedded into the json.